# Anchor tags not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to create a link on login form, that is by clinking "Signup" a user will be redirected to sign up form but when I create a link it does not work and come back after refreshing the page shortly.
My login page looks like this:-

**v_login.php**

```
<body>

<h1>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</h1>

  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
  <?php echo form_open('c_verifylogin/index');
     echo form_label("Username: ");
     echo form_input("username");
     echo "<br>";
     echo form_label("Password: ");
     echo form_password("password");
     echo "<br>";
     echo form_submit("","Login");
     echo form_close();

  ?>  
   **<a href="<?php echo site_url('c_signup/mylink_to_signup')?> " >Signup</a>**
  </body>
```

The controller for this login id:-

**c_login.php**

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class C_login extends CI_Controller {
  function index() { 
    $this->load->helper(array('url','form','html'));
    $this->load->view('v_login'); //load view for login
     }      
}
```

my signup controller is:-

**c_signup.php**

```
   <?php
   class c_signup extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct() {

   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->helper('url'); 
   $this->load->model('m_regt'); 
   }
   function mylink_to_signup(){

    $this->load->view('v_signup');
    }
     function index()
      {

   // Including Validation Library

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
      {

      $this->load->view('v_signup');
             }
    else
         {
    // Setting Values For Tabel Columns
   $data = array(
   'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
     'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
     'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
     'profession' => $this->input->post('profession')
       );
      // Transfering Data To Model
     $this->m_regt->form_insert($data);
  // Loading View

    //$this->load->view('v_login');
    }
     }
      }
      ?>
```

and the Signup view is:-

**v_signup.php**

```
  <div id="container">
  //sign up form here

   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have any `mylink_to_signup` function in `c_login` controller so it will be

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('c_signup/mylink_to_signup');?>" >Signup</a>
```

Comment: there is no error. page gets refresh shortly and again come backs to same login page but url gets chage like here i am getting "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php?c_signup/mylink_to_signup"

Comment: then try with full url like <a href="localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/c_signup/mylink_to_signup" >Signup</a>

Answer (score 1):

Check out URL helper in codeigniter which has an anchor function for creating anchor tags

The tag has three optional parameters:

anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)
The first parameter can contain any segments you wish appended to the URL. As with the site_url() function above, segments can be a string or an array.

Note:  If you are building links that are internal to your application do not include the base URL This will be added automatically from the information specified in your config file. Include only the URI segments you wish appended to the URL.

The second segment is the text you would like the link to say. If you leave it blank, the URL will be used.

The third parameter can contain a list of attributes you would like added to the link. The attributes can be a simple string or an associative array.

Here are some examples:

echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', 'title="News title"');
Would produce: [My News](http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123)

echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', array('title' => 'The best news!'));
Would produce: [My News](http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123)
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept the answer.

Comment: How to remove index.php from url in this case? It automatically adds index.php

Comment: dude you need to put an htaccess file in your root directory to remove the index.php in your url . Let me know if you you want the contents of the htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Please look there was a space on your url:

```
 **<a href="<?php echo site_url('c_signup/mylink_to_signup')?> " >Signup</a>**
```

Try change it:

```
 <a href="<?php echo site_url('c_signup/mylink_to_signup')?>">Signup</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem. there was actually a helper link for query string enable/disable in cofig file .

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

i changed this to TRUE that's why the links were not working. 
Thanks all for your help.`